# How to evaluate a string in IF?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, expression, eval

I've a string that contains a condition like `"$a==1||$b==2||$c==3"`.

What should I do to evaluate this string (as a condition) using IF statement?

Comment: *"What should I do to evaluate this string (as a condition) using IF statement?"* - Sure, why not. Did you try it? Could even look into the ternary operator if it's gets weirdly.

Comment: *"I've a string that contains a condition like "$a==1||$b==2||$c==3""* - Those aren't strings, they're integers or you're wanting to compare apples with oranges. Why don't you show us your real code and how you're using it, or wanting to use it?

Comment: So you have a dynamic condition and want to check it?

Comment: Since there are questions leaning towards [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), I'll just leave you with a user-contributed note: _If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the
wrong question. -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP_

Comment: Since nobody bothered to ask the proper question: where does the string come from? Fix the input instead. This entire thing smells like an XY problem to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Eval function](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.eval.php) to evaluate it, but first, you need to concatenate some code:

```
$yourString = "$a==1||$b==2||$c==3";
$evalString = "if(".$yourString .")return true;";
$evaluation = eval($evalString);
```

in this case above, if any of terms are true, will return true.

OBS: the variables $a,$b,$c should be declared before the execution.

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate this condition you can use eval().
For example:

```
$a=1; $b=33; $c=1;

$condition = '$a==1||$b==2||$c==3';
eval('$isTrue = ' . $condition . ';');
echo intval($isTrue); // should output 1
```

You want to be careful with eval(). I wouldn't recommend using it unless you really have to AND you're confident that $condition is not something anyone can tamper with.

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected end of file in .. .php eval()'d code on line 1`. I shouldn't need to mention that `eval` is ruuude

Comment: Thanks FirstOne. I was missing semicolon :)

Comment: Not saying that I agree with `eval()`, but remember that you need `$a` `$b` and `$c` to exist... ASSUMING that it will be those names the next time... see, so many problems.. **avoid this at all costs**

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy. try this

```
<?php

   $a="yes";
   $b="ok";
   $c="yes";

   if(($a=='yes') || ($b=='ok') || ($c=='yes')){
   echo "If a=yes or b=ok or c=yes you got this";
   } else {
   echo "You got this, because a!=yes or b!=ok or c!=yes";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [eval()](http://docs.php.net/eval) - which in your context will probably be a nightmare in regard of limiting the expression to only what you want to/should allow - you can create a parser/lexer that can only handle those operations you want.
You can e.g. take a look at the pear packages [PHP_LexerGenerator](https://pear.php.net/package/PHP_LexerGenerator) and [PHP_ParserGenerator](https://pear.php.net/package/PHP_ParserGenerator). Or search stackoverflow for answers regarding `[php] parser`.

---

And just for fun:
[PHP 7 introduced](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/abstract_syntax_tree) an  [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) layer to its compilation process.
The extension at https://github.com/nikic/php-ast exposes this AST layer to the userland script. Using this [a) limited to php7+, b) unclear whether this extension will be maintained in the future, I just found it via google ] you can set up an interpreter like e.g.

```
<?php
$data = [
    ['a'=>5, 'b'=>6, 'c'=>7],
    ['a'=>5, 'b'=>6, 'c'=>3],
    ['a'=>5, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>7],
    ['a'=>1, 'b'=>6, 'c'=>7],
    ['a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>7],
    ['a'=>7, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3],
];
$expressions = [
    '$a==1||$b==2||$c==3',
    '($a==1&&$b==2)||$c==3',
    '$a==1&&($b==2||$c==3)'
];

foreach( $expressions as $x ) {
    $ep = new ExpressionParser($x);
    echo $x, "\r\n";
    foreach( $data as $scope ) {
        $result = $ep->eval( $scope );
        printf(
            "   %s => %s\r\n", 
            compact_var_export($scope),
            compact_var_export($result)
        );
    }
}

class ExpressionParser {
    public function __construct($expr) {
        $ast = ast\parse_code('<?php '.$expr.';', $version=20);
        if (!$ast || ast\AST_STMT_LIST!=$ast->kind ) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('unable to parse expression');
        }
        else if ( 1!==count($ast->children) || ast\AST_BINARY_OP!==$ast->children[0]->kind ) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('only one binary expression allowed');
        }
        else {
            $this->ast = $ast->children[0];
        }
    }

    public function eval($scope) {
        return evalOp($scope, $this->ast);
    }
}

function evalOp($scope, $ast) {
    static $handler = null;

    if ( is_null($handler) ) {
        $handler = [
            ast\AST_UNARY_OP => [
                ast\flags\UNARY_BOOL_NOT    => function($scope, $c) { return !evalOp($scope, $c[0]); },
                ast\flags\UNARY_BITWISE_NOT => function($scope, $c) { return ~evalOp($scope, $c[0]); },
                ast\flags\UNARY_MINUS       => function($scope, $c) { return -evalOp($scope, $c[0]); },
            ],

            ast\AST_BINARY_OP => [
                ast\flags\BINARY_BOOL_AND            => function($scope, $c) { return evalOp($scope, $c[0]) && evalOp($scope, $c[1]); },
                ast\flags\BINARY_BOOL_OR             => function($scope, $c) { return evalOp($scope, $c[0]) || evalOp($scope, $c[1]); },
                ast\flags\BINARY_BOOL_XOR            => function($scope, $c) { return evalOp($scope, $c[0]) ^ evalOp($scope, $c[1]); },
                ast\flags\BINARY_IS_IDENTICAL        => function($scope, $c) { return evalOp($scope, $c[0]) === evalOp($scope, $c[1]); },
                ast\flags\BINARY_IS_NOT_IDENTICAL    => function($scope, $c) { return evalOp($scope, $c[0]) !== evalOp($scope, $c[1]); },
                ast\flags\BINARY_IS_EQUAL            => function($scope, $c) { return evalOp($scope, $c[0]) == evalOp($scope, $c[1]); },
                ast\flags\BINARY_IS_NOT_EQUAL        => function($scope, $c) { return evalOp($scope, $c[0]) != evalOp($scope, $c[1]); },
                ast\flags\BINARY_IS_SMALLER          => function($scope, $c) { return evalOp($scope, $c[0]) < evalOp($scope, $c[1]); },
                ast\flags\BINARY_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL => function($scope, $c) { return evalOp($scope, $c[0]) <= evalOp($scope, $c[1]); },
                ast\flags\BINARY_IS_GREATER          => function($scope, $c) { return evalOp($scope, $c[0]) > evalOp($scope, $c[1]); },
                ast\flags\BINARY_IS_GREATER_OR_EQUAL => function($scope, $c) { return evalOp($scope, $c[0]) >= evalOp($scope, $c[1]); },
            ],

            ast\AST_VAR => function($scope, $a) {
                if ( !isset($scope[$a->children[0]]) ) {
                    throw new InvalidArgumentException('undefined variable: '.$a->children[0]);
                }
                else {
                    return $scope[$a->children[0]];
                }
            }
        ];
    }

    if ( !is_object($ast) ) {
        return $ast;
    }
    else if ( !isset($handler[$ast->kind]) ) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('unsupported operation type');
    }
    else if ( is_array($handler[$ast->kind]) ) {
        if ( !isset($handler[$ast->kind][$ast->flags]) ) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('unsupported operation');
        }
        else {
            return $handler[$ast->kind][$ast->flags]($scope, $ast->children);
        }
    }
    else {
        return $handler[$ast->kind]($scope, $ast);
    }
}

function compact_var_export($x) {
    return preg_replace('!\s+!m', ' ', var_export($x, true));
}
```

The output is

```
$a==1||$b==2||$c==3
    array ( 'a' => 5, 'b' => 6, 'c' => 7, ) => false
    array ( 'a' => 5, 'b' => 6, 'c' => 3, ) => true
    array ( 'a' => 5, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 7, ) => true
    array ( 'a' => 1, 'b' => 6, 'c' => 7, ) => true
    array ( 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 7, ) => true
    array ( 'a' => 7, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, ) => true
($a==1&&$b==2)||$c==3
    array ( 'a' => 5, 'b' => 6, 'c' => 7, ) => false
    array ( 'a' => 5, 'b' => 6, 'c' => 3, ) => true
    array ( 'a' => 5, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 7, ) => false
    array ( 'a' => 1, 'b' => 6, 'c' => 7, ) => false
    array ( 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 7, ) => true
    array ( 'a' => 7, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, ) => true
$a==1&&($b==2||$c==3)
    array ( 'a' => 5, 'b' => 6, 'c' => 7, ) => false
    array ( 'a' => 5, 'b' => 6, 'c' => 3, ) => false
    array ( 'a' => 5, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 7, ) => false
    array ( 'a' => 1, 'b' => 6, 'c' => 7, ) => false
    array ( 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 7, ) => true
    array ( 'a' => 7, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, ) => false
```

( I'm not really good at this. Therefore experts might find this clumsy, faulty or even plain wrong; feel free to comment ;-) )

Comment: And please keep [PeeHaa's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754965/how-to-evaluate-a-string-in-if#comment-59184760) in mind. This might very well be an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).